# CSS - Get CheckBox Value

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm following this article
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

for a checkbox, but how do I set and get the check value?
As I need to a do a post back with the value.

```
<label class="container">Accept Offers?
<input type="checkbox" id="Offers" name="Offers"/>
span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: You input does not have a `value` attribute (so by default it posts back `"on"` if checked and nothing if unchecked). Why are you not binding to a model?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Offers"  value="checkedValue" name="Offers"/>
```

If you see the Request.Form object or query-string (in case of HTTP GET submission) you will see the value, If this is not checked null will be seen or Request.Form will have not that key that belong to Checkbox.